# Getting sequential pointers for the coordinates of a vtkPoint data

Tags: c++, pointers, vtk

I wrote the following function to store the (x, y, z) of a `vtkPoint` in an array of type `double` and size of `3*N`, where `N` is the number of vertices (or points).

```
double* myClass::getMyPoints(void)
{
    double* vertices = new double[this->m_numberOfVertices * 3];    
    for (vtkIdType ivert = 0; ivert < this->m_numberOfVertices; ivert++)
        for (auto i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            this->m_points->GetPoint(ivert, &vertices[3 * ivert]);

    return vertices;
}
```

where `m_points` is a member of `myClass` and is of type `vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>`.

This function does what I want and works just fine. I was wondering if there is an elegant way of getting the sequential pointers. I tried [`GetVoidPointer()`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPoints.html#a6790380ebdd771dd29a9b69a254fb53e), which looks like an elegant one-line code, to avoid the `for` loop but it does not get the coordinates correctly after the function returns `vertices`.

```
(double*)(m_points->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0));
```

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vtkPoints` internally stores it's data as a `float` array instead of a `double` array. So you may need to modify your function to work with `float*` instead of `double*`. If we want to use `double` array for `vtkPoints` then we should call [`SetDataTypeToDouble()`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPoints.html#ab0a83925b150274179aacf344e72ea85) on the `vtkPoints` object.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vtkPoints.h>
#include <vtkSmartPointer.h>

int main(){
    // Create data
    auto N = 5;
    vtkNew<vtkPoints> pts;
    pts->SetDataTypeToDouble();
    for(auto i=0; i < N; ++i)
         pts->InsertNextPoint(rand()%100,rand()%100,rand()%100);

    // Read using for loop
    std::cout<< "Using for loop ... " << std::endl;
    for( auto j=0; j < N; ++j ){
         double p[3];
         pts->GetPoint( j, p );
         std::cout<< p[0] << "," << p[1] << "," << p[2] << std::endl;
    }

    // Read using GetVoidPointer()
    std::cout<< "Using GetVoidPointer() ... " << std::endl;
    auto data_ptr = (double*) pts->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0);
    for( auto k = 0; k < N; ++k )
           std::cout<< *(data_ptr + 3*k) << ","
                 << *(data_ptr + 3*k + 1) << ","
                 << *(data_ptr + 3*k + 2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives result as follows:

```
Test that there are N = 5 tuples.
Using for loop ... 
83,86,77
15,93,35
86,92,49
21,62,27
90,59,63
Using GetVoidPointer() ... 
83,86,77
15,93,35
86,92,49
21,62,27
90,59,63
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and providing a nice example. Seems like the issue was using a `double` pointer rather than a `float`.

Comment: Is there anyway to allow `vtkPoints` to store values as `double`?

Comment: Yes. I will try to add an example.

Comment: I just realized that `vtkPoints` provides a function called `SetDataTypeToDouble()` for the exact same purpose that we want. I have updated my example accordingly.